# How to create a SQLite login form and registration form?

Tags: android

loginpage.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    ImageButton ib1,ib2;
    EditText e1,e2;
    ImageView iv;
    LoginDataBaseAdapter loginDataBaseAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=new LoginDataBaseAdapter(this);
        loginDataBaseAdapter=loginDataBaseAdapter.open();

        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
        e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_search);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_login_heading);
        b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.image_login);
        ib1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib_username);
        ib2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.ib_password);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login_notnow);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String userName=e1.getText().toString();
                String password=e2.getText().toString();

                if(password.equals(password))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Congrats: Login Successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.i(""+userName, "name");
                    Log.i(""+password, "pass");
                    Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,JobsCategery.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User Name or Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("clixk","notnow");
            }
        });
        b3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("click","sucess");
                Intent intent1=new Intent(MainActivity.this,RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent1)
                ;      }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my login page when I try to login, it gets successful login from wrong userid and password. I want to use correct code.

In my register page from which new user register, they both are taking wrong values and getting successful. I want code that works.

register.java

```
 public class RegisterActivity  extends Activity{
TextView tv1,tv2;
Button b;
EditText e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6;
ImageView iv;

SignupDtaBaseAdapter  signDataBaseAdapter;
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.register);
// get Instance  of Database Adapter
    signDataBaseAdapter=new SignupDtaBaseAdapter(this);
    signDataBaseAdapter=signDataBaseAdapter.open();

tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_register_job);
tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_fill_data);
   b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_name);
  e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password);
   e4=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_phone);
  e5=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_repass);
   e6=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_username);
  iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_search);
  b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String emailid=e1.getText().toString();
    String name=e2.getText().toString();
    String password=e3.getText().toString();
    String contact=e4.getText().toString();
    String retypepassword=e5.getText().toString();
    String userName=e6.getText().toString();
    // check if any of the fields are vaccant
    if(userName.equals("")||password.equals("")||emailid.equals("")||name.equals("")||retypepassword.equals("")||contact.equals(""))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Field Vaccant", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
    }
            Log.i(""+userName, "name");
        Log.i(""+password, "pass");
        Log.i(""+emailid, "mailid");
        Log.i(""+name, "name");
        Log.i(""+contact, "contact");
        Log.i(""+retypepassword,"retypepassword");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent=new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
       });
   }
      }
```

Comment: u r comparing password with itself..

Comment: `password.equals(password)` you are comparing the same String????

Comment: sir can you give me example of this code..please

Comment: @bakriOnFire is there any solution for this???

Answer (score 1):

your password isn't dynamic.
If you have a database for this application your password matching should come from there.
You can create your password manually and try. For ex;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String pass = "123456";
}
if(password.equals(pass)){
//your code
}else{
 //your code
}
```

As I said, if you have a database yoou can match the passwords.

Comment: sir but i am making a dynamic application in which diffrent2 user will login and register,so i caanot keep it temparory..

Comment: Which web service are you using ? Where are you sending the username and password ? The informations should come from web service so you can compare them.

Answer (score 0):

```
password.equals(password))
```

you are comparing the same passwords, you will always get a true :)

Comment: so what should be the answer

Comment: that you know i presume.. Because only you can figure out what has to be compared against the password isn't it ? The best thing to do would be to debug and find out what should go in the condition.

Comment: can you give me any example related to this,its very urjent please...:(

Comment: you could do this, if you are not using webservices and its a temp thing, then u can store the username in a string or sharedPreferences, compare the username with the username stored and the same for the password. if both of the username and password are correct then valid, else if either one of them fails then invalid login

Comment: i am using webservice and i am making application of job portal in which i have to keep two login user login and registeration..,how to perform this opreation.

Comment: if you are using webservices then simply pass in the username and password, and based on the response recvd you can specify if the username and/or password is correct or not..